# Is it possible to add a post_build_step in CMAKE with user input?

Tags: python, jenkins, encryption, cmake

We want to encrypt our binaries via a post_build_step in CMAKE.

Lets imagine the following python script (enc.py)

```
import base64
import hashlib
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random

BLOCK_SIZE = 16
pad = lambda s: s + (BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE) * chr(BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE)

def encrypt(raw, password):
    private_key = hashlib.sha256(password.encode("utf-8")).digest()
    raw = pad(raw)
    iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
    cipher = AES.new(private_key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    res = cipher.encrypt(raw.encode("utf8"))
    return base64.b64encode(res)

text = "the binary to encrypt..."
passw = input("Enter encryption password: ")
encrypt_text = encrypt(text, passw)
print("origin text: {}".format(text))
print("encrypted text: {}".format(encrypt_text))
```

And the following cmakelists.txt

```
# Check if python is available
find_package(Python3 COMPONENTS Interpreter)
if (NOT ${Python3_FOUND})
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Python is needed!")
endif()

add_custom_command(TARGET APP_NAME POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${Python3_EXECUTABLE} ${SCRIPTS_DIR}/enc.py )
```

Is this common practice, or is there a better way?

Considering, this has also to run on a build server like Jenkins.

Comment: Instead of POST_BUILD step, I would better ask an encryption key on **configure** stage, e.g. via [execute_process](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/execute_process.html) invocation. Usually it is assumed, that building gives **same results** every time, and asking additional parameters at building step will break this assumption. You could also create a CACHE variable for store user responce. So in automatic builds you could pass this variable via command line: `cmake -DENCRYPT_PASSWORD=<...> ...` and do not ask user for a password.

Comment: You should use `REQUIRED` with `find_package` rather than an `if` statement.